# Can @emotion/core @emotion/styled emotion-theming be used with electron?

Tags: emotion, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm trying to integrate emotion into my electron app but having some troubles and can't seem to find any talk of it. The boilerplate I'm using is [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate). Everything seems to be working during the development build, but as soon as I build for production I get this error:

[image]

Any guidance or help would be great! I've seen there are some advanced options with emotion theming that I might need to use such as `CacheProvider` but not sure how to use them with electron....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In `app/index.tsx` you need to set the container the scripts will be injected into manually using `CacheProvider` and `createCache`, since the actual ReactDOM.render happens inside a document event listener. Full `index.tsx` file here:

```
import 'styles/index.css'

import createCache from '@emotion/cache'
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/core'
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer as ReactHotAppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'

import Root from './containers/Root'
import { configureStore } from './store/configureStore'

const AppContainer = process.env.PLAIN_HMR ? Fragment : ReactHotAppContainer

const { store, persistor } = configureStore()

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const myCache = createCache({
        container: document.head,
    })

    // Render
    return render(
        <CacheProvider value={myCache}>
            <AppContainer>
                <Root store={store} persistor={persistor} />
            </AppContainer>
        </CacheProvider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
})
```